Which is better when using a program that produces output to STDOUT the program's output option or output redirection
Is there any advantage/disadvantage to using a commands output option (usually -o) if you can just use output redirection (>).
Originally this question was specifically pertaining to cURL but after testing this out on cURL myself I noticed that the STDOUT of cURL included a lot more information than just the actual HTML such as status codes, and headers.
However if a program produces the same STDOUT as an output option would is there any difference between picking redirection over the output file option? (besides being able to append or merge with output redirection).

I think you are looking at the STDER not STDOUT. Unless you redirect one of the two, both are printed to the terminal. When you do command > file you are only redirecting STDOUT, the status codes will still be shown.

Neither is better, they just have different use cases. First of all, not all programs write to standard output, so sometimes you must use their option to provide an output file name. Conversely, not all programs have such an option, so sometimes you must redirect.
More generally, in the cases where you have the choice, you can use whichever you prefer for what you are doing. If, for example, you are running the command as a different user using sudo, then the redirection will be run as your regular user and won't have the elevated privileges conferred by sudo:
$ sudo curl unix.stackexchange.com > /unix.se
bash: /unix.se: Permission denied

This is because the redirection, the >, isn't part of curl, so has no connection with the sudo and is being run as your regular user. This is also why the error appears even before I am prompted for a password. So here, using curl's -o is one possible way around that problem:
$ sudo curl unix.stackexchange.com -o /unix.se
[sudo] password for terdon: 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   167  100   167    0     0   3037      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3092

Conversely, if for instance you want to append multiple pages to one file, then you can't use -o because that will overwrite the file's contents:
$ for url in unix.stackexchange.com google.com duckduckgo.com; do 
   curl  -o mysites.all "$url" 2>/dev/null
 done
$  grep -ic '<head>' mysites.all 
1

As you can see above, we only have one <head> tag in the output file, because each iteration overwrote the previous contents. If we were to instead redirect output using >, we would get everything:
$ for url in unix.stackexchange.com google.com duckduckgo.com; do 
  curl "$url" 2>/dev/null
 done > mysites.all
$ grep -ic '<head>' mysites.all 
3

On the other hand, sort has the -o option which writes the output file only after processing all the input, allowing to use a same file for both input and output. This can't be done with a redirection, as the shell will open and truncate the output file even before starting the command itself.
So, there is no better or worse option, they are just useful in different context. If both work for you, feel free to choose whichever you prefer.

Thanks so much for this response, I had no clue that output redirection wouldn't run as root if the other command was run with sudo.
